# How to avoid make <enter> in org-agenda view limited to current buffer to open a new view on buffer?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I started using org-agenda-view limited to current buffer to get a kinda of a outline of the current file (using `<` Buffer, subtree/region restriction)

Works great in that it splits the window in 2 and I have outline in one, full text buffer in other.

What is annyoing though is that when I press enter to jump to TODO item in the agenda view it don't just jump back to the original buffer/view but opens a new one so now I have two views onto the same buffer.

Is there a setting to have it just keep using same buffer ?

Answer (score 1):

of course just after this I realized TAB does this automatically.

That was easy :)

Comment: Please elaborate, to make your answer more useful.

Comment: OK so actually Enter opens the org file in the same buffer as the org agenda while Tab opens the file in another buffer. That's helpful information I think I already forgot from the original documentation.